# Apache - Custom Handler

Tags: apache

Please consider the following 2 example lines from an Apache config file:

```
Action xyzHandler /cgi-bin/xyzHandler
AddHandler xyzHandler .xyz
```

I understand that the effect of the above 2 lines is to "map" files that end with a .xyz extension to the executable /cgi-bin/xyzHandler. I would like to better understand what is meant meant by the term, "map".  Does it mean that the contents of the file ending with a .xyz extension is applied to the standard input of /cgi-bin/xyzHandler?  Does it mean that a path to the file ending in the .xyz extension is passed as an argument to /cgi-bin/xyzHandler? Does it mean something else?  What exactly does it mean?

Thanks  for any input.

... doug

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, it turns out that this question is answered here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html.  In a nutshell, the answer is this:  The /cgi-bin/xyzHandler script is simply executed.  A path to the file ending with a .xyz extension that triggered the execution is made available via the standard CGI PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED environment variables.  Thanks to all for your indulgence.

```
 ... doug
```